# Redirect output from both time and grep into file

Tags: bash, scripts

When running this command, time measurements come to stdout and the grepped string are redirected to the file.

```
$console:time curl <URL> --silent -v 2>&1| grep <string of verbose curl output> > file_with_both_time&grepped_string

real    0m0.146s
user    0m0.070s
sys     0m0.005s
$console: cat file_with_both_time&grepped_string
> grepped string from verbose curl output
```

Wondering how I can grab it all in a single redirect.

I have a load balanced cluster and I'm measuring how long it takes to run a command on each hosts and if it takes longer to run a command, I want to know which host it is(Can get from curl output).